# Semantic UI with Heroku - 404

Tags: node.js, heroku, http-status-code-404, semantic-ui

I'm trying to push my node app to heroku, but the `semantic.css` and `semantic.js` are not found on the server. Everything works fine locally (even with a new install with only `npm install` and `npm start`).

They are served in my `app.js`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/jquery', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/jquery/dist/')));
app.use('/semantic', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/semantic/dist/')));
```

The `jquery.js` file is retrieved (and served like the semantic files).

The `semantic/dist` directory is filled using a gulp task, runned by the `npm postinstall` script.

While deploying the heroku app, I can see those warnings :

```
Ignoring local @import of "../../../semantic/src/definitions/tab.css" as resource is missing.
Created: semantic/public/semantic/components/tab.css
Plumber found unhandled error:
Ignoring local @import of "../../../semantic/src/definitions/transition.css" as resource is missing.
Starting 'package compressed css'...
Created: semantic/public/semantic/components/transition.css
Starting 'package uncompressed css'...
Plumber found unhandled error:
Ignoring local @import of "../../../../semantic/public/semantic/components/semantic.min.css" as resource is missing.
Finished 'package compressed css' after 1.6 s
Created: semantic/public/semantic/semantic.css
Finished 'package uncompressed css' after 1.5 s
Finished 'build-css' after 20 s
Finished 'build' after 20 s
```

What am I missing ?

**EDIT**

After some debugging (ie: running `ls semantic` in the postinstall script) it seems that the dist folder is not generated in the semantic folder. Why is that?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am getting the same error.

Comment: @igor-vuk I dont really remember but I think I managed to serve it using gulp (set the output in the public folder)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible problem:

`app.use('/semantic', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/semantic/dist/')));`

You're using `path.join` and concatenating `(__dirname + '/semantic/dist/')` instead of passing in two paramaters: `(__dirname, '/semantic/dist/')`

Comment: Well, that's a mistake, but I did the same mistake to serve another library (highcharts) and it is served. As you can see in my edit, the main problem is that the dist folder is not generated in the semantic directory